# Handling conditions at class level based on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to frame this question, I am looking to solve a design problem.

I'm using ActiveRecord.

An `Agency` can have multiple `documents`.

`documents` has a column `additional_details` of type `jsonb`. Contains hash details.

`additional_details` column has different set of key value pair based on `agency`.

Example:

```
doc1 = agency1.documents.first.additional_details => { xml_url: '', ... }
doc2 = agency2.documents.first.additional_details => { feed_url1: '', ... }
```

agency1 and agency2 are instance objects of Agency.

---

When I make a call to fetch the url like **`document.additional_details.get_url`**

I can write conditions like

```
def get_url
  if agency1.name == 'Utah'
    return additional_details[xml_url]
  elsif 
    so on
  elsif
    so on
  end
end
```

Which is not a good practice I feel.

I believe we can solve this at class level. Note I need to solve this on presentation layer, I'm using decorators .

Edit:

An particular agency will have same keys within additional_details column but values are certainly different.

Comment: Isn't the name of the key where the URL is found in the additional_details an attribute of the agency? Then it should go into the agency table as column. It is not clear to me what you mean by `if agency1`. Is `agency1` a variable or does it stand for something like `if self.name == "Some special agency"`?

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke you are right, I have updated it. Also check my edit section

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these are Active Record classes? Where is `agency1` defined? You should almost never be hard coded based on specific instances, instead any such data should be part of the record and its instance.

It is especially unclear why you have different types of "URL" at all, and not just a simple `url` string column in the `documents` table. Why does `agency1` use `xml_url` but `agency2` uses `feed_url1`?

But as an example, if each agency has say a prefix defined (say the domain name / filestore, and the documents just the relative/local address), say:

```
agency1.document_root = "https://example.com/documents/"
agency1.documents.first.rel_url = "web/rails/rails_example.pdf"
```

Then in the `Document` class you might do:

```
def url
  agency.document_root + rel_url
end
```

Which then gives you the:

```
agency1.documents.first.url
```

Comment: I'm using activerecord, agency1 and agency2 are AR objects.

Comment: based on agency, the url differs. that's the whole point I'm trying to solve.

Comment: But it cant be just a `document_root` or some other "template"?

Comment: It can't, an agency will have same keys within additional_details column but values are certainly different

Comment: Well, really you need to force some sort of consistency or pattern. Whatever is in that `if`, `elsif` chain really needs to be actual data on the `Agency`. And you need to give a clear and simple example of the differences. Otherwise you will just keep getting the same thing, like my `document_root` or `url_key` from Sven Koschnicke.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your `Agency` model where you store the key to the url in the additional data hash. Let's say you name the field `url_key`. Then you can do

```
def get_url
  additional_details[agency.url_key]
end
```

Note that I assume that `get_url` is a method on the `Document` model.

Comment: `get_url` is used as an example here. I can't do this at agency level

Comment: @Nithin can you refine the example in your question to make clearer that it is not possible to do that? I would like to understand, why.